# A micro-reversible stochastic process that models transitions between states with variable energies

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have a system with 3 possible states A, B and C (there could be $n$ states as well) with energies $E_a(t)$, $E_b(t)$ and $E_c(t)$ that vary with time.

If our system has a constant finite temperature it can perform transitions between  the states A, B and C with a certain probability that depends on their energies.

Is anyone aware of a micro-reversible stochastic process that can models these transitions?

In simpler terms I need something like this (suppose we are at the A state currently):

If $E_a$ is close to $E_b$ and $E_c \gg E_b$ I would like to try to jump to the state B.

If $E_b$ and $E_c \gg E_a$ I would like my system to stay as is.

I am already aware of a model where the probability to jump depends on the energy of the current state and there is 50% chance to jump in any candidate state but this does not work in my case since $E_b$ or $E_c$ might get very large.

Comment: Do you know about [detailed balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detailed_balance)? "Usually" one models such processes with transition rates whose ratios satisfy $p_{i\to j}/p_{j\to i} \propto \mathrm{e}^{-(E_j-E_i)/k_B T}$. This has the properties that you want, and moreover ensures the correct stationary (thermal equilibrium) distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Mark!

Well yeah the previews model i was using (the one with the equiprobable jumping between the candidate states) satisfied detailed balance.
The thing is i have yet to find any model in the literature that accounts for hopping on candidate states with a probability that depends on the energy of the final state..

Comment: Have you considered Monte Carlo method?

Comment: Yes, currently the state transitions are performed with a kinetic MC simulation. Those "states" are actually springs that connect polymer chains and perform jumps depending on their current energy (the height of the barrier is a parameter).

The scheme i currently use works fine for gaussian springs (which can extent indefinitely) thus the energy cant get too large. Now i need to work with Finete Extensible springs (FENE) hence i need a new scheme that prevents the state A to transition into state B if the energy of B is infinite (the final spring is too large).

Comment: @ArisSgouros couldn't you choose the probability per unit time of a jump from state $i\to j$ to be $p_{i\to j} = \gamma\mathrm{e}^{-(E_j - E_i)/2k_B T}$? This satisfies detailed balance and suppresses jumps between states when their energy difference is large (and positive).

Comment: I don't quite understand what's your problem. If have three states with energy $E_A$, $E_B$ and $E_C$. The probability are then $e^{-E_A/k_BT}$, $e^{-E_B/k_BT}$ and $e^{-E_C/k_BT}$. With very high energy, the probability is very low and thus it becomes a very small event that MC will unlikely to choose the state. If somehow FENE has some significant probability with high energy, then it is a possible event. Why do you worry about this?

Comment: @Mark Mitchison

Thanks a lot both of you for you time

Well i think i resolved the issue while maintaining detailed balance, let me show you what i did.

The spring is initially at state A with Ea and in order to hop to neighboring nodes 
(eg. states B and C) - hence forming a new spring with energy Eb or Ec - it needs to cross an energy barrier Ek with 
probability exp(-(Ea-Ek)/kBT). The value of the energy barrier is not known and its given as a parameter. 
Ek is assumed to be greater than Ea, Eb and Ec and that assumption worked fine with gaussian springs but not with FENE.

Comment: In order to work with FENE springs what i did was to calculate beforehand the length of the candidate spring before the 
hopping attempt, and if its length is greater than the maximum allowed i exclude it from the candidate list since this
is an impossible state with infinite energy.

I hope i got this right..